# Facing issues to get matched element in same order from Json Object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, javascript-objects

I am having string with column names and trying to get value of matched element from the json object with key,value

```
var str=""Object Status","Reason","Date From","Date To","Object Number",";
```

I am having Json Object inside an array

```
dataResult.Objects[0]={OBJECT_NUMBER:123,OBJCET_STATUS:"NEW",DATE_FROM:"/Date(1587764199000)/",DATE_TO:"/Date(1619755200000)/",REASON:"FRESHCOPY"}
```

I am trying to loop through array and try to get matched element but I shoudl be expecting them in the same order as the string values are present.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= dataResult.Objects.length; i++) {
            var item = dataResult.Objects[i - 1];
            var val = '';
            $.each(item, function (key, value) {
                var columnCollection = str.replace(/ /g, "").toUpperCase();
                var matchingKey = key.replace(/_/g, '');
                if (columnCollection.includes(matchingKey)) {
                    val += '"' + value + '",';
                }
            });

            }
```

I tried with the above code snippet but I am getting result like `"123,NEW,"/Date(1587764199000)/","/Date(1619755200000)/",FRESHCOPY"` but I want the data tobe in same order as string.
I am expecting the result should be `"NEW,"FRESHCOPY","/Date(1587764199000)/","/Date(1619755200000)/",123"`

Please let me know how can I achieve in the same order of string columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't something like that work for you?

```js
const str=`"Object Status","Reason","Date From","Date To","Object Number"`,
      obj =  {OBJECT_NUMBER:123,OBJECT_STATUS:"NEW",DATE_FROM:"/Date(1587764199000)/",DATE_TO:"/Date(1619755200000)/",REASON:"FRESHCOPY"},
      
      result = str
        .split(',')
        .map(key => 
          obj[key
            .toUpperCase()
            .replace(/\s/g, '_')
            .replace(/"/g,'')
          ])
        
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.It worked,can we convert the date to date format with in the same Map function.or else again we have to loop through and change date format for those fields

Comment: Thanks for response.I have modified code and able to get desired respnse

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through dataResult.Objects, loop through the str list and get the corresponding object from dataResult.Objects

Comment: I am having around 4k rows for data result,and string is only one row.so thought of looping thorugh data result rows.